# Stop navigation?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have 3 frames. One called "Setup" where you enter some details to get the program running, one called "Loading" which basically just shows a loading dialog while Things are set up, and one called "Chat" where the program can in fact be used.

Now, I'm trying to cancel a "go back" navigation from the "Chat" frame to the "Loading" frame, and then instead navigate on to the "Setup" frame.

So in other words, when I'm on the Chat frame and I hit "back", I want it to go to my "Setup" frame instead of my "Loading" frame.

Is this possible?

Comment: there are ways to achieve what you want but without any details it is rather hard to help... please show some code... what have you tried ?

Comment: Without knowing too much about WinRT yet, maybe you could handle Activated event of your loading view and redirect there to another view

Comment: Have a look at this post http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2012/03/02/winjs-how-to-cancel-the-navigation-from-a-page/ It seems you can cancel the navigation and then I presume you can substitute your own at that point.

Comment: That's WinJS. I don't understand that.

Comment: @Mathias For a frame maybe [Navigating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigating.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up performing 2 "GoBack" calls in the navigator. It's a hack, but it works, and allows me to go 2 steps back. I'm probably doing something wrong though.

If better answers arrive, I will mark them as answered instead.